# How to view application logging on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an aspnetcore 2.1 app running on azure.

I now want to view logging information to debug an issue that occurs only on Azure.

In the app, an `ILogger<>` is injected into the class and used:
   `this._logger.LogInformation("constructor**********************************************");`

If I run the app in VS, I can see the output in both the debug output window,  as well as the asp.net core web server output window.

I then publish and go on Azure and enable the Log Stream and view it. I do see information appearing in the log stream, but it is just the request information from IIS. I don't see any other log messages.

Is there anything else I need to do to see the logging information on Azure?

Comment: In Log Stream, there is **Application logs** and **Web server logs**.  Make sure you're viewing **Application logs** to see application console output (though it does also output web server logs).  The Web server logs only outputs web server (IIS) logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices/). The package describes itself as:

> Logger implementation to support Azure App Services 'Diagnostics logs' and 'Log stream' features.

Once you've installed the package, you'll need to update the logger configuration to use this new provider, which is usually done in `Program.cs`, like this:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
            })
            ...
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: I have done the steps outlined in this answer and I still see zero logger.Debug messages being shown in the log output. I see logs but they are not coming from my Serilog logger. 
How do I see these logs? Logging locally works great. Azure not so much.

Comment: @StephenPrice The approach is different if you're using Serilog and the `UseSerilog()` method, so you should look into that as a separate thing.

Comment: Worked out what I was doing wrong. I mistakenly thought the Console logs would show up in the Azure stream. Instead I needed to add a File sink and then find the log files as files on the site. Hope this helps someone else out, it was a bit puzzling

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Application Insights with your application to see the logs generated.

You can read the steps from  [`Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log)

Comment: This was a very good tip.  I had no idea that Tracing was including in Application Insights.  I enabled it locally and was able to see the message in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and configure Azure Application Insights for your project.

By configuring the Instrument Key in your application you can send all the kinds of logs from your application to Application Insights.

*Install the below Nuget*

**`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.2.0 NuGet packages`**

**Configure the Application Insights in you asp.net core application**

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
// Change to file post adding Application Insights Telemetry:
                .UseApplicationInsights()
//
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```

[See this step by step instruction on how to configure application insights into your asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-core)